# XSLT Nested to Flat structure

Tags: xslt

I'm new with XSLT and I'm struggling with a transformation from a nested structure to a flat sequence of elements.
My input is like the following:

```
<SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM>
<EBMHeader/>
<DataArea>
  <Sync/>
  <SyncBillOfMaterialsList/>
  <SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
        <Identification>
            <ID>B31819K</ID>
            <ContextID schemeID="AddedBOMs"/>                         
        </Identification>
        <BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/>
 </SyncBillOfMaterialsList>

 <SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
    <Identification/>
    <BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>
        <Identification>
             <BusinessComponentID schemeID="B31819K"/>
             <ID>B31618R</ID>
             <ContextID schemeID="AddedBOMComponents"/>             
        </Identification>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <FromUnitNumber>500</FromUnitNumber>
        <TypeCode>IT1</TypeCode>      
        <BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/>      
    </BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>   
</SyncBillOfMaterialsList>

<SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
    <Identification/>
    <BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>
        <Identification>
             <BusinessComponentID schemeID="B31819K"/>
             <ID>B31619S</ID>
             <ContextID schemeID="AddedBOMComponents"/>     
        </Identification>
       <Quantity>2</Quantity>
       <FromUnitNumber>600</FromUnitNumber>     
       <TypeCode>IT1</TypeCode>      
    </BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>   
</SyncBillOfMaterialsList>

<SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
    <Identification/>   
    <BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>
        <Identification/>
            <BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem>
                 <Identification>
                    <BusinessComponentID schemeID="B31819K"/>
                    <ID>B31618R</ID>
                    <ContextID schemeID="AddedSubstitutes"/>                        
                 </Identification>
                <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                <ItemReference>
                    <ItemIdentification>
                       <ID>B31619S</ID>               
                    </ItemIdentification>
                    <SpecificationGroup/>
                </ItemReference>
                <ChangeTypeCode>IT1</ChangeTypeCode>
            </BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem>      
    </BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>   
</SyncBillOfMaterialsList>

<SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
   <Identification/>       
   <BillOfMaterialsComponentItem>
      <Identification/>       
      <BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem>
         <Identification>
            <BusinessComponentID schemeID="B31819K"/>
            <ID>B31619S</ID>
            <ContextID schemeID="AddedSubstitutes"/>                
         </Identification>
         <Quantity>2</Quantity>
         <ItemReference>
            <ItemIdentification>
               <ID>B31820L</ID>
                            </ItemIdentification>
         </ItemReference>
         <ChangeTypeCode>IT1</ChangeTypeCode>         
      </BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem>      
    </BillOfMaterialsComponentItem> 
</SyncBillOfMaterialsList>
```

The output should be a list of elements like the following

```
        <InputParameters>         
        <REV_ITEM>                    
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME>B31819K</REVISED_ITEM_NAME>
        </REV_ITEML>
        <REV_COMP>      
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>B31618R</COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                
        </REV_COMP>
        <SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>                   
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME>B31819K</REVISED_ITEM_NAME>                    
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>B31618R</COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                   
                <SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>B31619S</SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>
                <SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>5</SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>
        </SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>
    </InputParameters>

    <InputParameters>         
        <REV_ITEM>                    
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME>B31819K</REVISED_ITEM_NAME>
        </REV_ITEML>
        <REV_COMP>      
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>B31618S</COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                
        </REV_COMP>
        <SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>                   
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME>B31819K</REVISED_ITEM_NAME>                    
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>B31618S</COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                   
                <SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>B31619L</SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>
                <SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>2</SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>
        </SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>
    </InputParameters>
```

My XSLT is not working at all since is iterating only in one element at each time and I cannot find the way to iterate over all the elements and get the right values in the same structure.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each  select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID/@schemeID != '' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/ID!='' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/ItemReference/ItemIdentification/ID!='' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/Identification/ID=/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID@schemeID AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID@schemeID=/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/ItemReference/ItemIdentification/ID >
    <REV_ITEM>                    
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/Identification/ID"/></REVISED_ITEM_NAME>
    </REV_ITEML>
    <REV_COMP>      
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/ID" /></COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                
    </REV_COMP>
    <SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>                   
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/Identification/ID"/></REVISED_ITEM_NAME>                    
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/ComponentItemProcessingInstruction/Identification/ID" /></COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                   
                <SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME><xsl:value-of select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/ItemReference/ItemIdentification/ID"/></SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>
                <SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY><xsl:value-of select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/Quantity"/></SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>
    </SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>


    </xsl:when test="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID/@schemeID != '' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/ID!='' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/BillOfMaterialsSubstituteComponentItem/ItemReference/ItemIdentification/ID='' AND /SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/Identification/ID=/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID@schemeID">

    <REV_ITEM>                    
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/Identification/ID"/></REVISED_ITEM_NAME>
    </REV_ITEML>
    <REV_COMP>      
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME><xsl:value-of select="/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/ID" /></COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                
    </REV_COMP>
    <SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>                   
                <REVISED_ITEM_NAME><!--empty--></REVISED_ITEM_NAME>                    
                <COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME><!--empty--></COMPONENT_ITEM_NAME>                   
                <SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME><!--empty--></SUBSTITUTE_COMPONENT_NAME>
                <SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY><!--empty--></SUBSTITUTE_ITEM_QUANTITY>
    </SUB_COMP_TBL_ITEM>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:when OTHERPOSIBILITIES>
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- EMPTY -->
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help is much appreciated, it is take me a lot of struggle to create and manipulate a variable to point in the right value.

Answer (score 0):

1. This will not produce well-formedXML, because the template that matches the root node results in a document with three document elements.
2. Your xslt is not well-formed.  Having closed your first when element, you need to open another one.
3. If you find yourself writing a `for-each`, then trying to test some characteristic of the node in question, then you should probably be using apply-templates instead.
4. None of your `REVISED_ITEM_NAME` elements will be populated, as there is no `SyncBillOfMaterialsList` element with a child element of `SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM`.
5. Create XPath expressions relative to the context node, rather than trying to find it again from document root based on `position()`.  e.g. Instead of:
   `/SyncBillOfMaterialsListEBM/DataArea/SyncBillOfMaterialsList[position()]/BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID/@schemeID`, just use `BillOfMaterialsComponentItem/Identification/BusinessComponentID/@schemeID`.  This is more readable, and the use of `position()` can be fragile, as it does not refer to the ordinal position of a node within its parent, but to its position within the current node list.  If you have an XPath expression that explicitly selects a node which is the fifth child within its parent, `position()` will be 1, not 5.
6. Don't try to create the whole tree based on a collection of conditions evaluated at once.  It looks like each `InputParameters` element in your output has the same shape, but with different values.  So in your `SyncBillOfMaterialsList` template, specify the shape of the `InputParameters` tree once, and populate its child elements conditionally.  That will be far more maintainable and easy to read.